# split string into array C++

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, getline

How do I split an input string using `getline(cin, input);` to input the variable? I want to split it into a char array like this:

```
char[] = { // What goes here to make it read the input variable and split it into chars }
```

Is there any way to do this?

And what about y'all's new posts? Which one is best? Here is the caesar cipher code I need to modify to read the input variable and store its chars in a char array:

```
// Test Code ONLY
// Not A Commercial Program OR A Crypter
// THIS IS A TEXT CIPHERER

#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string in;
    string out;
    char lower[25] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z};
    char upper[25] = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z};
    char upcip[25] = {Z,Y,X,W,V,U,T,S,R,Q,P,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A};
    char locip[25] = {z,y,x,w,v,u,t,s,r,q,p,o,n,m,l,k,j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a};
    cout << "Enter PlainText: ";
    getline(cin, in);
    // which sample goes here to read the input var char by char, then store the chars in order in a char array in your opinion?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? `std::string::c_str()` will return a pointer to a null-terminated char array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Updated OP with code I'm trying to edit.

Answer (score 4):

A string **is** already an array of chars:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, e = line.size(); i != e; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "char[" << i << "] = '" << line[i] << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;
    std::getline(cin,str);
    char* pArr = new char[str.size() + 1]; // add 1 for zero element which is the end of string
    strcpy(pArr,str.c_str());

/*
some actions with pArr, for ex.
while(*pArr)
    std::cout << *pArr; // output string on the screen

*/

// updated: release memory obtained from heap
delete [] pArr;
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete the array once you're done with it. And for exception safety, it really should be managed by some kind of RAII type, such as `std::string`.